# Google Charts add blank space/whitespaces in Chart Title

Tags: c#, html, css, charts, google-visualization

How do I add blank space or whitespcaes in the chart title.
I tried &nbsp and &#160 but it is not working.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

labels in google charts (title, legend, axis) will not accept html,
but you can use Unicode characters...

in this case, use the non-breaking space --> `\u00A0`

```
title: 'Begin>\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0<End'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 6]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Begin>\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0<End'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works.
Is this '\u00A0' non-breaking space different for different browsers?