# Reverse the bar chart in google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I am trying to create a bar chart using google charts but I need to reverse the directions of the bars. I have achieved it by setting `hAxis: { direction: -1,}` 
But the problem is only the direction of bars is reversed and the y axis labels are not placed accordingly as shown in the picture.
[image]

How can I change the placement of y-axis labels to come to the right of y -axis?
My code:

```
function drawBasic() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Locations', 'Product count',{role:'annotation'}],
      ['Bengaluru', 277, '277'],
      ['Hyderabad', 182, '182'],
      ['Chennai', 139, '139'],
      ['Kolkata', 136, '136'],
      ['Jaipur', 78 , '78 ']
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: 'none',
      chartArea: {width: '50%'},
      colors: ['#3cb371'],
      hAxis: {
        direction: -1,
        gridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
        minValue: 0,
        textPosition: 'none'
      },
    };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think it is possible get the same result as the one you show in your question, but, it *might* be an alternative:

- Use the non-breaking space --> `\u00A0` for add white spaces between the value shown in the bar and the start of the axis. [**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833123/12511801)

If you follow the tip I mentioned above, you should change the chart's settings as is shown in this [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/r0tk51L7/7/).

Here's the code:

```js
/*
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833123/12511801
*/

google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Locations', 'Product count', {
      role: 'style'
    }, {
      role: 'annotation'
    }],
    ['Bengaluru', 277, 'color: #3cb371;', '277\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Bengaluru'],
    ['Hyderabad', 182, 'color: #3cb371;', '182\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Hyderabad'],
    ['Chennai', 139, 'color: #3cb371;', '139\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Chennai'],
    ['Kolkata', 136, 'color: #3cb371;', '136\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Kolkata'],
    ['Jaipur', 78, 'color: #3cb371;', '78\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Jaipur']
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: "", // Title of the chart.
    //width: 600,
    //height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: '', // Title below the x-axis
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      direction: -1,
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent',
        count: 0
      },
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: '', // No title.
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent',
        count: 0
      },
      minValue: 0,
      textPosition: 'none', // Option: set the text at the end of the bar.
      allowHtml: true
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  //chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

---

If the previous modifications doesn't accomplish your requirements, you have to change the way how to draw that data (*either by using another chart API or modify your current code AND draw the text in a separated div and somehow align this chart results to your text*).